# how can i convert my class into a namespace

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

i have a class in c++ that i want to convert to a namespace
i have tried to look around in google but i couldn't find any solution that will make my class a namespace.
how do i do that? its a class that contains 3 functions.
for example:

```
class c
{
public:
    void A();
    void B();
    void X();
}
```

i want to be able to use these functions without creating a new object of the class, i want to to be a namespace.
class C that has functions a(),b(),x(), will turn into a namespace.
p.s, i have CLion 2017
ty

Comment: If you want to use functions `A`, `B`and `C` without an instance of the `c` class, the implementation of these functions potentially needs to change significantly. It's somewhat hard to tell you what to do because it depends on how these functions are implemented.

Answer (score 6):

It's much easier than you think.

```
namespace c
{
    void A();
    void B();
    void X();
}
```

Comment: and how i include that in my main.cpp?

Comment: @YoavLinder In the same way as you would include the class definition.

Comment: i triedd, but it doesnt recognize that. its matked in red

Comment: @YoavLinder You also need to use the same syntax (using the "scope resolution" operator, `::`) as when you access things in the `std` namespace - `c::A();`, and so on.

Comment: @YoavLinder   Did you *try* compiling it. Your IDE is **not* the compiler, just because it colours the code a certain way does not necessarily mean the compiler won't accept it.

Comment: yes, that gives an error DSP.h: No such file or directory

Comment: @YoavLinder That's a completely unrelated issue. It means that your compiler can't find that file. You may need to check the settings in your IDE.

Comment: @YoavLinder you need to provide a [MCVE]

Comment: if i change it to class  instead of namespace it doesnt find that also, you know what can be the problem?

Comment: This change doesn't work since the member functions weren't originally `static`. Without evidence to the contrary you have to assume `this` is meaningful. The meaning or usage of those functions must be significantly altered for this change to be applicable.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That depends on whether these objects have any state (and whether there is more than one). Stateless objects ("quasiobjects?") are fairly common, in particular among those who have learned a little bit about OOP and nothing about anything else, or had an object-obsessed teacher.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like this:

**foo.cpp**

```
#include "bar.h"

int main()
{
  bar::A();
  bar::B();
}
```

**bar.h**

```
namespace bar
{
  void A();
  void B();
}
```

**bar.cpp**

```
#include "bar.h"

namespace bar
{
  void A()
  {
    ...
  }

  void B()
  {
     ..
  }
}
```

This is a minimal example without header guards for brevity.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use static functions

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    static void A();
}
```

You then may call those functions like this :

```
MyClass::A();
```

Comment: only recommendable if you want to still be able to have instances of  `MyClass`

Comment: Of course ! If you never intended to instanciate MyClass then use a namespace (molbdnilo answer).

Comment: @Korni Or if you need it as a type parameter for a template.